# Polymer override script loaded by HTML import

Tags: google-chrome-extension, polymer, web-component

Is it possible to access a (Polymer) web component's dependency (also a component) which the only thing it does is load a js script, and override that with another (newer version in my case) script?

Concrete problem: I'm using various Polymer elements (say [paper-dialog](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dialog) for example) which use [neon-animation](https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-animation) whose different animations all import the [web-animations](https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-animation/blob/master/web-animations.html) HTML which loads the script I want to override.

In other words I would like to perform something like what the `/deep/` combinator does for CSS to penetrate into this specific HTML 'component' and add a newer version of the `web-animations-next-lite.min.js` script.

As for the why: the idea is to use a Chrome extension to perform this since remote update is not an option (internet connectivity limitations). I need to do this since with Chrome v54 our app "broke" (since we use an older web-animations version) by fixing the WebAnimations API so [these](https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-animation/issues/162) [errors](https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js/issues/72) broke animations and with that functionality (popups not appearing).

I already tried injecting the newer version script in my main HTML body with Chrome extension's content script but didn't have any luck there..

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

I know its a bit of a hack, but can't you just put your own version of the web-animations script in bower_components.  The problem with trying to alter the polymer element in place is that it will have already loaded the script before you can get at it.

Comment: Nope, if I could do that I would properly upgrade the element itself instead.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the `load` event on you HTML Imports `<link>`, then add a `<script>` element with the right `src` attribute.

It's this last downloaded (and parsed) script that will be taken in account.

```
<script>
   function loaded() {
      //file.html loaded
      document.write( '<script src="new-file.js"></script>' )
   }
</script>
<link rel=import href="file.html" onload="loaded()">
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do, but how do I listen for a load event on a specific HTML import? `WebComponentsReady` fires *after* all imports are loaded but even then, I need to override specifically `web-animations.html` and not insert the script tag in my body cause it needs to target the Polymer element. Already tried injecting the script in `body` but it didn't work.

Comment: @Viktor I've added an example but i think that if it doesn't work WebComponentedReady it won't work with onload since it is also fired after parsing...

Comment: This could work if I have access to the file. Remember I cannot add the  `onload="loaded()"` attribute. If I could do that I would upgrade/replace the whole script instead... :/

Comment: Did you try with HTMLImportLoaded event?